# Sorting a dictionary by date with unicode indexes django

Tags: list, dictionary

I have a dictionary, like this

```
available= [(u'Small w/b',
{
'20/08': {'total': 18, 'availability': 10, 'full': False},
'19/08': {'total': 18, 'availability': 5, 'full': False},
    '23/08': {'total': 18, 'availability': 9, 'full': False},
    '22/08': {'total': 18, 'availability': 11, 'full': False}, 
    '21/08': {'total': 18, 'availability': 16, 'full': False}
    }),
('dates', ['19/08', '20/08', '21/08', '22/08', '23/08']),
(u'Medium', 
    {
    '20/08': {'total': 32, 'availability': 29, 'full': False},
    '19/08': {'total': 32, 'availability': 32, 'full': False},
    '23/08': {'total': 32, 'availability': 31, 'full': False},
    '22/08': {'total': 32, 'availability': 30, 'full': False},
    '21/08': {'total': 32, 'availability': 29, 'full': False}
    }),
(u'Matrimonial', 
    {
    '20/08': {'total': 3, 'availability': 3, 'full': False}, 
    '19/08': {'total': 3, 'availability': 2, 'full': False}, 
    '23/08': {'total': 3, 'availability': 3, 'full': False},
    '22/08': {'total': 3, 'availability': 2, 'full': False},
    '21/08': {'total': 3, 'availability': 3, 'full': False}
    }),
(u'Large',
    {
    '20/08': {'total': 30, 'availability': 26, 'full': False},
    '19/08': {'total': 30, 'availability': 21, 'full': False},
    '23/08': {'total': 30, 'availability': 25, 'full': False},
    '22/08': {'total': 30, 'availability': 25, 'full': False},
    '21/08': {'total': 30, 'availability': 25, 'full': False}
    }), 
(u'Backpacker', 
    {
    '20/08': {'total': 12, 'availability': 4, 'full': False},
    '19/08': {'total': 12, 'availability': 6, 'full': False},
    '23/08': {'total': 12, 'availability': 11, 'full': False},
    '22/08': {'total': 12, 'availability': 6, 'full': False},
    '21/08': {'total': 12, 'availability': 7, 'full': False}
    })]
```

Right now is looking like this. I want to iterate over the two dictionaries and ORDER the dates inside every item to the right order.  How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot order the keys of a dictionary because `dicts` are unordered.
However, you can turn the key value pairs into a list of tuples using `items()` and then using `sorted` to sort the list:

```
for elem in available:
    if elem[0] != 'dates':
        print sorted(elem[1].items())
```

will print out:

```
[('19/08', {'total': 18, 'availability': 5, 'full': False}), ('20/08', {'total': 18, 'availability': 10, 'full': False}), ('21/08', {'total': 18, 'availability': 16, 'full': False}), ('22/08', {'total': 18, 'availability': 11, 'full': False}), ('23/08', {'total': 18, 'availability': 9, 'full': False})]
[('19/08', {'total': 32, 'availability': 32, 'full': False}), ('20/08', {'total': 32, 'availability': 29, 'full': False}), ('21/08', {'total': 32, 'availability': 29, 'full': False}), ('22/08', {'total': 32, 'availability': 30, 'full': False}), ('23/08', {'total': 32, 'availability': 31, 'full': False})]
[('19/08', {'total': 3, 'availability': 2, 'full': False}), ('20/08', {'total': 3, 'availability': 3, 'full': False}), ('21/08', {'total': 3, 'availability': 3, 'full': False}), ('22/08', {'total': 3, 'availability': 2, 'full': False}), ('23/08', {'total': 3, 'availability': 3, 'full': False})]
[('19/08', {'total': 30, 'availability': 21, 'full': False}), ('20/08', {'total': 30, 'availability': 26, 'full': False}), ('21/08', {'total': 30, 'availability': 25, 'full': False}), ('22/08', {'total': 30, 'availability': 25, 'full': False}), ('23/08', {'total': 30, 'availability': 25, 'full': False})]
[('19/08', {'total': 12, 'availability': 6, 'full': False}), ('20/08', {'total': 12, 'availability': 4, 'full': False}), ('21/08', {'total': 12, 'availability': 7, 'full': False}), ('22/08', {'total': 12, 'availability': 6, 'full': False}), ('23/08', {'total': 12, 'availability': 11, 'full': False})]
```

Comment: But is there a way to convert it to a ordered list or something?

Comment: Yeah, can do that.  Also, is there a reason why `available[1]` has a list?

Comment: ok i did that,  but how do I order the "sublists" inside? Is there a way?